# installing CouchDB 1.0.1 on Ubuntu 10.04 using http://www.couch.io/get#ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, couchdb

I was wondering what are the steps do i need to perform for installing couchdb using the package from http://www.couch.io/get#ubuntu ?

I understand that i need to run

> sudo chmod a+x name-of-file.bin

and than

> sudo ./name-of-file.bin

to install it.

But after doing the above steps, what do i need to do to start couchdb version 1.0.1?

I've previously installed couchdb using

> sudo aptitude install couchdb

, 
but this gives me version 0.10.0.

I've tried start couchdb ( version 1.01) by going to /opt/couchdb-1.0.1/bin to start couch, but after checking , couchdb's version is still 0.10.0.

SO how do i install and start running couchdb ( version 1.0.1 )?

Best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May I suggest you use our [stable ppa](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntuone/+archive/stable)? CouchDB from there will be landing in 10.04 backports soon.

Comment: Hello, sure i'll try that and get back to you. Do i have to remove all previous versions of CouchDB before installing the latest version from the stable ppa ?

Comment: by the way, after adding the stable ppa, do i install couchdb using sudo aptitude install couchdb?

Comment: If you haven't had it installed before, yes. If you already had installed couchdb 0.10, it should just upgrade (but it won't upgrade the databases).

Comment: wow, thanks. another question, may i know what do u mean by "it won't upgrade the databases"? Thanks!

Comment: The databases live in `/var/lib/couchdb/<couch version>/`. If you copy the ones from `/var/lib/couchdb/0.10.0/` to `.../1.0.1/`, they will be upgraded automatically. This is not done by the package automatically because you can't really "undo" it.